# $wpdb->get_results breaking page?

Tags: php, pages, wpdb

I'm trying to generate a list of years that have posts on a Wordpress page using a "php in posts" plugin that has a shortcode. but the code I'm using seems to break the page.

What could be the issue here?

```
[insert_php]
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'results' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year DESC" );
 foreach ( $years as $year ) {
    echo '<h2>' . $year->year . '</h2>';
}
[/insert_php]
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem would be to use a plugin that uses <s>`evil()`</s> `eval()` to evaluate string as PHP, in the first place ;-)

This part is from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> Caution The `eval()` language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Most likely the `global $wpdb` is missing, but I would suggest to you to just create your own shortcode instead.

**Example:**

```
add_shortcode( 'tim_daniels_list', function( $atts = [], $content = '' )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $years = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year 
         FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
         WHERE post_type = 'results' AND post_status = 'publish' 
         GROUP BY year DESC" 
    );
    $html = '';
    foreach ( (array) $years as $year ) {
        $html .= '<h2>' . $year->year . '</h2>';
    }
    return $html;
});
```

Comment: Ahh yes you're right, simple fix! Should have known really :')
If possible, could you let us know about the potential danger of eval() and benefits of using a shortcode instead?

Comment: I updated with a quote from the PHP manual. @timdaniels